# DynamoDB UPDATE if existing else PUT - Boolean

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to have a table with the structure

```
{
userId : 123,
Tracking: true
}
```

It is possible that the user does not exist for the first operation. So, by default a false should be set. The next request makes this value true, 3rd request makes it false again and so on. Similar to NOT(Tracking) i.e writing a negation to the value.

I could do this by reading the table, negating the value in the my lambda function and updating the table with new attributes.

This would mean a GET and UPDATE request for the DB. I am looking for a way to send a negation flag instead.  In this way I just write a false if the user is not existing.  If the user is existing, I would toggle between true and false depending on the already existing boolean value.

Just wondering if there is a way to do this. It would be then a single update request to the DB. Any pointers would be helpful.

I did not find much help from the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#update-property

Comment: UpdateItem will update an item if it already exists, and add an item if it doesn't exist. It doesn't make sense to me that you would submit an item with Tracking: true and expect it to be modified to false if the item doesn't already exist. Why would you have indicated Tracking: true in this case?

Comment: I know its too late to ask, just wondering if you found a solution for this @Sriharsha

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a boolean you can use an integer. Increment it by 1 each time and then use even as true, odd as false (or reversed)

Comment: The value can get as high as 10 to 100000 in a single day. I am worried that at some high value, DynamoDB will not accommodate it anymore. For example, over 38 digits after a few months

Comment: You could perform 1,000,000 writes per second for 1 year, incrementing the value by one each time and the value would only be 31,536,000,000,000 or 3.1e13 which is a long way from 1e38.